# CakePHP custom values on select input

Tags: php, html, cakephp

I am trying to create a select input field. However I want to set the values of each individual option manually.

in an attempt I tried the following:

```
echo $this->Form->input('field', array(
    'options' => array('Active', 'Blocked', 'Pending', 'Unknown'),
    'values' => array(1,2,0,99),
    'empty' => '(choose one)'
));
```

However this did not help (i.e 'Active' was 0, 'Blocked' was 1 etc...)

Does anyone know if it is possible to manually set the values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

values is not the right key, you need to leverage the options array for it, as well:

```
'options' => array(1 => 'Active', 2 => 'Blocked', 0 => 'Pending', 99 => 'Unknown'),
```

but that is basic PHP (since non-defined keys are numerically indexed starting off at 0).

Answer (score 2):

You’ll need to use an associative array to set the keys as well:

```
$options = array(
    '1' => 'Active',
    '2' => 'Blocked',
    '0' => 'Pending',
    '99' => 'Unknown'
);
echo $this->Form->input('field', array('options' => $options));
```

However, I’d advise storing options like this in a separate database table rather than hard-coding them, to keep your views [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and allowing them to be easily modified in the future.